# Extraer enlaces con BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup, scraping

estoy intentando sacar ciertos enlaces desde una url, que tiene bloques de código como este:

```
<div class="posting-card super-highlighted " data-id="55399753" data-posting-type="DEVELOPMENT" data-to-posting="/propiedades/ceibos-point-55399753.html" data-index="2" data-key="2">
```

Lo que quiero es extraer el texto `"/propiedades/ceibos-point-55399753.html"` que corresponde a `data-to-posting`, he estado intentadolo con el método `find_all` pero no he logrado conseguirlo. Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: Publica el còdigo que haz escrito, junto con sus resultados. Sin ver lo que haz hecho, imposible opinar.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que esta pregunta en el foro en inglés puede ayudarte: [enlace a la pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21592012/extract-class-name-from-tag-beautifulsoup-python/21592363)

Básicamente, lo que hace es convertir el código html en un diccionario y, a partir de ahí, busca el campo requerido.
Espero que te sea de ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Lo he resuelto de la siguiente manera:

```
soup.find("div", {"class": "posting-card super-highlighted", "data-to-posting": True})['data-to-posting']
```